# Match only numbers between the first and second comma in regex

Tags: regex, numbers, match

Example strings:

`John, a 005, green, 01-22-18.abc
 Sarah, 325, blue, 03-18-17.abc
 Mike, b 56, red, 12-05-17.abc`

I would like regex to match `005` `325` and `56` respectively. Could you show me how to accomplish it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this.`([0-9]*),`

Comment: Doesn't work. Thanks for trying. https://regex101.com/r/k8qGBo/1

Comment: To me its work https://regex101.com/r/ddNEQc/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match numbers that occur between first and second comma in each line:

```
^[^,]*,[^,0-9]*([0-9]+)
```

Numbers are available in capture group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8qGBo/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^[^,]*,`: Match anything until first comma and then the comma at start
- `[^,0-9]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not comma or digits
- `([0-9]+)`: Match 1 or more digits and capture it in group #1

Comment: How do I extract the "group #1" only?

Comment: Text parser module of Integromat. Here https://www.integromat.com/en/integrations/regexp

Comment: Hmm I don't know Integromat but extracting a capture group is possible in all the editors or tools

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regex engine you could use 
[Positive Lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/8699120) and [Positive Lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/8699120).

```
(?<=,\W|\s)\d+(?=,)
```

**Explanation in order of execution:**

- `\d+` Matches one or more digits
- `(?<=,\W|\s)` preceded by a comma and a non-word character or a whitespace
- `(?=,)` and is followed by a comma.

**Try it here:**

https://regex101.com/r/nkYBFh/1

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, this regex phrase doesn't work in Notepad++. Any idea why?

Comment: Not all regex engines support lookaheads/lookbehinds.